More moderators - New Elections
Quant Finance has 3 moderators, @Olaker, @BobJansen and @SRKX.
From what I observe BobJansen is a regular and very active moderator. As of today Olaker has not been seen on the site since 10th Feb according to his profile, and SRKX seems active but personally I don't observe his/her actions.
Now don't get me wrong I'm not criticising those I cite at all - I know how life works and priorities shift. My point is simply that 3 moderators does not necessarily seem enough, and against the backdrop of the combined activity leaves scope for floating the idea of more?
Personally I do not have the required reputation, nor the time or dedication to be a moderator but it does not stop me from raising the question which I cannot see has been broached since 2017.

Organizing new moderator elections is currently being looked into.

Just bumping this. The last moderator election was 2019? When are new elections run?
